# formatting the output log file using awk sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have few rows in my log file, like:

```
www_liferay.log.2016-04-06-09:09:28:11|88.196.217.216+Su3XAR2l+LR15563413|INFO |e.e.p.i.RequestLogInterceptor|render MultiSimPackageChangeController(POST)      susgRefNum=10953115     action=MultiSimPackageChangeController.addContract|
www_liferay.log.2016-04-06-09:09:28:23|88.196.217.216+8vNPzjWX+LR15563413|INFO |e.e.p.i.RequestLogInterceptor|render MultiSimPackageChangeController(POST)      susgRefNum=10953119     action=MultiSimPackageChangeController.addContract|
www_liferay.log.2016-04-06-09:09:36:08|88.196.217.216+09ROHqBk+LR15563413|INFO |e.e.p.i.RequestLogInterceptor|render MultiSimPackageChangeController(POST)      susgRefNum=10953119     action=MultiSimPackageChangeController.addContract|
www_liferay.log.2016-04-06-10:10:14:50|62.65.33.194+cIvtH8Ju+LR2132626|INFO |e.e.p.i.RequestLogInterceptor|render MultiSimPackageChangeController(POST) susgRefNum=12229566     action=MultiSimPackageChangeController.addContract|
```

So, I need to construct grep/awk/sed command to get this output:

```
09:28:11|88.196.217.216 LR15563413 susgRefNum=10953115
```

So I should use something like that?

```
first column (09:28:11|88.196.217.216) data between patterns ":" and "+" 
second column (LR15563413) data between patterns "+" and "|" and
third column (susgRefNum=10953115) between spaces
```

Timestamp and IP address can change, LRxxxxx numbers can change too, so the are not constants.

To get the first column I used it like this:

```
awk -F: '{print $2 ":" $3 ":" $4}' testfile.txt | head -1 | awk -F+ '{print $1}' | head -1
```

and got something like that:

```
09:28:11|88.196.217.216
```

If you can, please explain to me the flags/options you use.

Thanks!

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question for us to provide a great answer. It would be helpful if you could include some additional log lines to demonstrate any anomalies or challenges that might crop up with the formatting. A translation based on just one sample has a higher risk of being fragile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this tested version a try:

```
sed -n '{ /^.*:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9][|][0-9.]*[+].*[+]LR[0-9]*[|].*susgRefNum=[0-9]*[^0-9].*$/ { s/^.*:\([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9][|][0-9.]*\)[+].*[+]\(LR[0-9]*\)[|].*\(susgRefNum=[0-9]*\)[^0-9].*$/\1 \2 \3/ p } }'
```

**-n** option instructs **sed** to not print lines, unless **p** is used.

**sed** reads line by line and use regular expression. Please read the famous pages:

- [Regular Expressions](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html)
- [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial by Bruce Barnett](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

a first regular expression select lines which match your pattern:

```
^.*:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9][|][0-9.]*[+]
```

> it should start with chars followed with :HH:MM:SS|IP+

```
.*[+]LR[0-9]*[|]
```

> it should continue with any sequence of chars until +LRnnnnn| (n is a digit, [0-9] in regexp)

```
.*susgRefNum=[0-9]*[^0-9]
```

> it should continue with any sequence of chars until susgRefNum=nnnnnn

```
.*$
```

> then it can end with any sequence of chars

If the curent line read (stored in the pattern buffer) matches, then **s** command (search and replace) is used to modify the pattern buffer and remove all unwanted sequence of chars.

The **s** command :

```
s/regexp/replacement/flags
```

**\(** and **\)** are used to select a particular sequence in the regexp used with **s**. This particular sequence can be referenced in the **replacement** part with **\1**. If more than one sequence is selected, then **\1** **\2** etc. can be used.

Finally, the resulting pattern buffer is printed with **p**.

Any line which does not match is not printed.

The test is below:

```
$ cat myfile.log 
www_liferay.log.2016-04-06-09:09:28:11|88.196.217.216+Su3XAR2l+LR15563413|INFO |e.e.p.i.RequestLogInterceptor|render MultiSimPackageChangeController(POST)      susgRefNum=10953115     action=MultiSimPackageChangeController.addContract|
www_liferay.log.2016-04-06-09:09:28:23|88.196.217.216+8vNPzjWX+LR15563413|INFO |e.e.p.i.RequestLogInterceptor|render MultiSimPackageChangeController(POST)      susgRefNum=10953119     action=MultiSimPackageChangeController.addContract|
www_liferay.log.2016-04-06-09:09:36:08|88.196.217.216+09ROHqBk+LR15563413|INFO |e.e.p.i.RequestLogInterceptor|render MultiSimPackageChangeController(POST)      susgRefNum=10953119     action=MultiSimPackageChangeController.addContract|
www_liferay.log.2016-04-06-10:10:14:50|62.65.33.194+cIvtH8Ju+LR2132626|INFO |e.e.p.i.RequestLogInterceptor|render MultiSimPackageChangeController(POST) susgRefNum=12229566     action=MultiSimPackageChangeController.addContract|
another line / another format

$ sed -n '{ /^.*:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9][|][0-9.]*[+].*[+]LR[0-9]*[|].*susgRefNum=[0-9]*[^0-9].*$/ { s/^.*:\([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9][|][0-9.]*\)[+].*[+]\(LR[0-9]*\)[|].*\(susgRefNum=[0-9]*\)[^0-9].*$/\1 \2 \3/ p } }' myfile.log 
09:28:11|88.196.217.216 LR15563413 susgRefNum=10953115
09:28:23|88.196.217.216 LR15563413 susgRefNum=10953119
09:36:08|88.196.217.216 LR15563413 susgRefNum=10953119
10:14:50|62.65.33.194 LR2132626 susgRefNum=12229566
```

Comment: can you explain it to me too please? It is very hard to understand for me

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r 's/^[^:]*:([^+]*).*\+([^|]*).*(susgRefNum=[^ ]*).*/\1 \2 \3/g' file
```

`^[^:]*:` --> matches until first occurrence of `:`

`([^+]*)` --> get string until next `+` is found ie eg `09:28:11|88.196.217.216`

`.*\+` --> matches string until next `+`

`([^|]*)` --> get string next `|`  ie eg `LR15563413`

`.*(` --> match until next `)` is found

`(susgRefNum=[^ ]*)` --> get string until next space is eg `(susgRefNum=[^ ]*)`

`\1 \2 \3` -->print what we got inside `()`

Answer (score 0):

awk has many string manipulation functions, you can use them:

```
awk -F'|' '{
   lr=substr($2, 1, index($2,"+")-1); sub(/.*\+/, "", $2);
   sub(/ [^ ]*$/, "", $5); sub(/.* /,"",$5);
   printf "%s|%s %s %s\n",substr($1, index($1,":")+1),lr,$2,$5;
}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F'[|+]| +' '{sub(/[^:]*:/,"",$1); print $1"|"$2,$4,$10}' file

09:28:11|88.196.217.216 LR15563413 susgRefNum=10953115
09:28:23|88.196.217.216 LR15563413 susgRefNum=10953119
09:36:08|88.196.217.216 LR15563413 susgRefNum=10953119
10:14:50|62.65.33.194 LR2132626 susgRefNum=12229566
```

**Explanation**

> `-F'[|+]| +'` by setting the field separator to `|` `+` and spaces you
>   can get rid of most the manual splitting.
>
> `sub(/[^:]*:/,"",$1)` strips the date from the date:time format in
>   field 1
>
> `print $1"|"$2,$4,$10` prints the selected fields split thanks to FS,
>   default separator is space where between first and second fields is
>   set to `|`.